# Decomposing a graph into double ray graphs

Tags: graph-theory

By a *double ray graph*, I mean a graph isomorphic to the graph whose vertices are $\Bbb Z$, the integers, and whose edges connect adjacent integers. (I'm not sure if this is the standard term or not. Perhaps another name would be "doubly-infinite path graph"?)

Some infinite graphs $G$ can be edge-decomposed into double ray graphs (meaning that no two have any edge in common, and that their union is all of $G$). Given a graph $G$, we can define$$n_G:=\{n\mid\text{$G$ can be edge-decomposed into $n$ double ray graphs}\}.$$

What are the possible values of $n_G$? Is there a graph such that $n_G=\{2,3\}$, for example?

Comment: Conjecture: all elements of $n_G$ are the same parity.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks. Some searching brought up the term _double ray_; I'll edit to use that.

Comment: For the infinite grid graph, $n_G = \mathbb{N}$, so not same parity

Comment: @caduk Surely $1\in n_G$ iff $G$ is the double-ray graph itself (I want the induced subgraph to be a double-ray, so I don't want a double-ray's vertices to intersect itself). I don't see how to get $2\in n_G$ in that example?

Comment: Sorry, I found trails, not double ray graphs...

Comment: Ok, I restore back my claim: For the infinite grid graph, $n_G=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$, so not same parity. To get 2, we start at (0,0) and make 4 spiraling paths (so 2 by 2, they make 2 double rays). To get one more, just add a vertical line crossing every edges on one column. The new graph is still an infinite grid.

Comment: @caduk I think I see it… something like this? https://i.imgur.com/Zy9MpWT.jpeg

Comment: @caduk My example with $n_G=\{2,4\}$ is this, by the way: https://i.imgur.com/Zy9MpWT.jpeg. See also these two images, which are a variation on the same: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hSeW.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/urE9L.png

Comment: Yes, it is it. First image for $\{2, 4\}$ is wrong I think? I found this example also (the one in the second image) while researching.

Comment: @caduk Ah. I meant to share this instead: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsBQr.jpg I must have copy/pasted the wrong link by accident.